# how to add custom block at shipping methods below in onepage checkout?

Tags: magento2

I want to add custom block below shipping methods and this custom block should be inside of shipping method form.
I think following line of code is helpful for adding this.but no idea how to proceed.

```
<div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
                    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('shippingAdditional') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### 1. Declare module's checkout dependency

> app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="NameSpace_ModuleName" setup_version="0.0.1" active="true">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

### 2. Overwrite checkout layout

> app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="additional_block" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">NameSpace_ModuleName/js/view/checkout/shipping/additional-block</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

### 3. Create JavaScript UI Component

Magento 2 checkout is manage in JavaScript (with Knockout).  So you need to create a custom JS compnent. It's will create the link between checkout UI component and your custom HTML template.

> app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping/additional-block.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent'

], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'NameSpace_ModuleName/checkout/shipping/additional-block'
        }
    });
});
```

### 4. Create HTML template

Then create the HTML template wich going to display in checkout.

> app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/shipping/additional-block.html

```
<div class="checkout-block" id="block-custom">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.</p>
</div>
```

### 5. Clear cache

Finally run following commands :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
chmod -R 777 var/*
```

> Download full example demo module from [here](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-additional-shipping-block)

Comment: really you are awesome.there is no end for magento community.its evergreen

Comment: Did you get these errors?

`Broken reference: No element found with ID 'checkout.header.wrapper'. [] []
Class SR\AdditionalShippingBlock\Model\CustomBlockConfigProvider does not exist [] []
[2016-04-13 10:15:06] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage [] []`

Comment: Tip for other noobs: the module needs to go in `app/code/SR/AdditionalShippingBlock`, not `app/code/Magento/AdditionalShippingBlock`.

Comment: @sohel rana, i would like to dynamic dropdown instead of textfield at same place, give me suggestion for that. Thanks.

Comment: Is this for real? :S wtf

Comment: There is an issue that the shipping comment is not saved to the db

Comment: Mindblowing, it's working. thank you so much brother.

Comment: An excellently comprehensive answer that works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: Why setup upgrade needed? `cache:clean` doed the job.

Comment: How to get textbox value in PHP file ?

Comment: my magento version is 2.2.2, i follow the same, but i couldn't get the result, any help please?

Comment: How can I add before Shipping Methods?

Comment: God bless you, bro! You saved my time :)

Comment: Can we add this before Shipping Method title or After the Phone Number?

Comment: To add block before shipping-method: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176327/1883

Answer (score 7):

In presented file "checkout_index_index.xml" there is one small mistake.
It must be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

not

```
<xml version="1.0"?>
```

Miss first char '?'

Comment: This could have been a commend on Sohel's answer.  In any case the file is correct in his repo https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-additional-shipping-block/blob/master/SR/AdditionalShippingBlock/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: Yes, of course. But I must have 50 reputation to comment;(