# Magento 2: How to add custom Block/Widget/Page on Checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, blocks, custom

Would like to add **CMS Page/Block/Widget** on Checkout Page before Shipping Method section.

How to achieve this?

Need to overwrite `magento\app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml`

Prefer **Block** When it's enabled from Admin it will display otherwise not.

Answer (score 2):

It's big solution. So follow step by step. You need to change Vendor and Modulename if needed.

**SR/StackExchange/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="before-shipping-method-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-shipping-method-form</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom_block" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">SR_StackExchange/js/view/custom-block</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**SR/StackExchange/view/frontend/web/js/view/custom-block.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function ($, ko, Component) {
    'use strict';
    console.log(window.checkoutConfig.custom_config);
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'SR_StackExchange/custom-block'
        },
        visibleCustomBlock: window.checkoutConfig.custom_config
    });
});
```

**SR/StackExchange/view/frontend/web/template/custom-block.html**

```
<!-- ko if:visibleCustomBlock -->
<h1>Custom Block</h1>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**SR/StackExchange/Model/CustomConfigProvider.php**

```
namespace SR\StackExchange\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

class CustomConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $store = $this->getStoreId();
        $custom_config = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('your/config/path', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

        $config = [
            'custom_config' => $custom_config
        ];
        return $config;
    }

    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
    }
}
```

**SR/StackExchange/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_config_provider" xsi:type="object">SR\StackExchange\Model\CustomConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Clear cache.

Comment: `$this->scopeConfig->getValue('your/config/path', $store)` This is Config value right. Need to use created Block so need to pass Identifier for that

Comment: Yes, it's system config value. You need to create your own system.xml for configuration.

Comment: Where can i set my Block "Identifier" which i created from Admin?

Comment: You need to pass all data through config param. because checkout render using knockoutjs.

Comment: It's almost this right? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92734/how-to-add-custom-block-at-shipping-methods-below-in-onepage-checkout

Comment: Yes, here config option is missing.

Comment: Do you want block content using AJAX?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52427/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-sohel-rana).

Comment: It's giving me Blank Page on Checkout

Comment: Current solution? if yes, then check following line $custom_config = 1;//$this->scopeConfig->getValue('your/config/path', $store);

Comment: It's displaying below "Shipping Methods" Text. How to show above that?

Comment: Would like to display Admin Block Content above "Shipping Methods" Text

Comment: Please look at my answer if we can work it out

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it requires coding or not.

Can we manage with this?

Go to **Admin -> Content -> Blocks**

Create Block Named: **Shipping Info**

Go to **Admin -> Content -> Widgets**

Create Widget & Save with below options

```
Layout Updates

Display On : Specified Page
Page: One Page Checkout
Container: Main Content Container
```

[image]
Select your created block. It will show Under "Shipping Methods" after all options.

Is there way we can show above "Shipping Methods" text? I'm not able to manage that.

**magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping.html**

Is there a way that we can make Position on above file. So requires less coding?