# Magento 2 - Add extra column to shipping methods

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, custom-field

I have a custom shipping method. By default, the Shipping Methods show 3 columns -

- Price,
- Method and
- Carrier.

I want to add another column that shows the estimated time of delivery.
How can I add the extra column?

I tried adding this to Vendor/Module/Model/Carrier/Rates.php

```
$method->setCarrier('customCarrier');
$method->setCarrierTitle('customCarrierTitle');
$method->setMethod('customMethod');
$method->setMethodTitle('customMethodTitle');
$method->setData('foo','customValue');
```

In the template file,

```
<tr class="row"
   click="element.selectShippingMethod">
   <td class="col col-method">
       <input type="radio"
              class="radio"
              ifnot="method.error_message"
              ko-checked="element.isSelected"
              ko-value="method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code"
              attr="'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code,
                   'checked': element.rates().length == 1 || element.isSelected" />
   </td>
   <td class="col col-price">
       <each args="element.getRegion('price')" render="" />
   </td>
   <td class="col col-method"
       attr="'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
       text="method.method_title" />
   <td class="col col-carrier"
       attr="'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
       text="method.carrier_title" />
    <td class="col col-foo"
       attr="'id': 'label_foo_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
       text="method.foo" />     
</tr>
```

The extra field 'foo' is not shown.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this one can help you get started https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92734/how-to-add-custom-block-at-shipping-methods-below-in-onepage-checkout?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I don't need an additional block, I need an additional column in the same block. How does Magento render the shipping methods?

Comment: you mean you want to display some extra column when your custom shipping is selected?

Comment: Yes, something like that can also work.

Comment: you can't do that as template file is using ko js to bind data

Comment: But it is using method.carrier_title and method.method_title. How is it getting these values?

Comment: wait for others they can help you

Comment: Have you did it?

Comment: No...as far as I understood, it cannot be done

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before by adding an extra field just below my custom shipping method and only display it when my custom shipping method is selected.

Follow this steps:
Create a plugin for the process method, `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor` in the path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Checkout/LayoutProcessorPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
   /**
    * @param LayoutProcessor $subject
    * @param array $jsLayout
    * @return array
    */
   public function afterProcess(
       LayoutProcessor $subject,
       array $jsLayout
   ) {
       $validation['required-entry'] = false;
       $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
       ['shippingAddress']['children']['custom-shipping-method-fields']['children']['input_custom_shipping_field'] = [
           'component' => "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract",
           'config' => [
               'customScope' => 'customShippingMethodFields',
               'template' => 'ui/form/field',
               'elementTmpl' => "ui/form/element/hidden",
               'id' => "input_custom_shipping_field"
           ],
           'dataScope' => 'customShippingMethodFields.custom_shipping_field[input_custom_shipping_field]',
           'label' => "Your Custom Label", //you can add your custom text here
           'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
           'visible' => true,
           'validation' => $validation,
           'sortOrder' => 2,
           'id' => 'custom_shipping_field[input_custom_shipping_field]'
       ];

       return $jsLayout;

}
```

Declare the plugin `Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin` for the class `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor` in your custom module’s **`di.xml.`**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
       <plugin name="checkout_custom_shipping_fields" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
   </type>
</config>
```

To include the custom input field in `shippingMethodItemTemplate`,  declare a region `custom-shipping-method-fields` under the section `shippingAddress` in the file path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                   <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                       <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                           <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                               <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                       <item name="shippingMethodItemTemplate" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/shipping-address/shipping-method-item</item>
                                                   </item>                                                   
                                                   <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                       <item name="custom-shipping-method-fields" xsi:type="array">
                                                           <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                           <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-shipping-method-fields</item>
                                                           <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                           </item>
                                                       </item>
                                                   </item>
                                               </item>
                                           </item>
                                       </item>
                                   </item>
                               </item>
                           </item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
               </argument>
           </arguments>
       </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

Override the `shipping-method-item.html` in the path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/

```
<tr class="row"
   click="element.selectShippingMethod">
   <td class="col col-method">
       <input type="radio"
              class="radio"
              ifnot="method.error_message"
              ko-checked="element.isSelected"
              ko-value="method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code"
              attr="'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code,
                   'checked': element.rates().length == 1 || element.isSelected" />
   </td>
   <td class="col col-price">
       <each args="element.getRegion('price')" render="" />
   </td>
   <td class="col col-method"
       attr="'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
       text="method.method_title" />
   <td class="col col-carrier"
       attr="'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
       text="method.carrier_title" />
</tr>
<!-- ko if: ((method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code == "customshipping_customshipping") && element.selectedMethod() == "customshipping_customshipping") -->
<tr class="custom-shipping-method-fields-shipping-information" >
   <td colspan="4">
       <div id="custom-shipping-method-fields-details-list-wrapper" data-bind="visible: method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code == 'customshipping_customshipping'">
           <!-- ko foreach: element.getRegion('custom-shipping-method-fields') -->
               <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
           <!--/ko-->
       </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
<tr class="row row-error"
   if="method.error_message">
   <td class="col col-error" colspan="4">
       <div role="alert" class="message error">
           <div text="method.error_message"></div>
       </div>
       <span class="no-display">
           <input type="radio"
                  attr="'value' : method.method_code, 'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code" />
       </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Note: change `customshipping_customshipping` according to your custom shipping method code.

Don't forget to run upgrade and redeploy static content.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and let you know

Comment: How can I set some data in Model/Carrier/Rates.php and display it in template?

Comment: did above code work for you?

Comment: for your new question you can create a block wherein you can put your public method and set a template (phtml) and in your template you can call it as `$block->yourPublicMethod();`

Comment: please post it as new question so others can help as well and maybe provide a better solution.

Comment: I tried using $method->setData('foo','someValue'); in Rates.php. How can I access this value in the template file? I tried using it as method.foo, but that doesn't work

Comment: if you can post your code ut will be easier to help. you can use a helper instead